# jar file doesn't finish installing

Tags: jar

I want to install: landserf230WindowsInstall.jar

I have: Windows 7 & the most recent Java (jre-8u211-windows-x64)

What I've tried:

1. When I run cmd as admin and paste the path file of the jar file `"C:\Users\Pet Monster\Downloads\landserf230WindowsInstall.jar"` the program doesn't finish installing. As in, it goes thru 3 of 5 of the installation windows. It even let's me choose install path. I've tried the default location `C:\Program Files\LandSerf`. when that didn't work, I tried `C:\Program Files (x86)\Landserf`.
2. entered this in cmd `C:\Windows\system32>java -jar landserf230WindowsInstall.jar C:\Users\Pet Monster
   \Downloads\landserf230WindowsInstall.jar` and got this 
   `Error: Unable to access jarfile landserf230WindowsInstall.jar`
3. I tried the same 2 steps with an older version of java and ran into the same 2 outcomes

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I recently did a clean reinstall of Windows and have all the system updates. I had this same program installed on the same laptop prior to my clean reinstall.

Question: How can I install the above jar file?

Answer (score 0):

usually when a jar file itself is an installer
i had to use JDK instead of JRE

and run the java -jar. (java in the jdk\bin ) 
may be can you try this and let know.

i faced similar one, during weblogic installation

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer!
I installed JavaSetup8u211 instead of jre-8u211-windows-x64 and it Landserf works perfectly now!